# Xcode Signal SIGABRT in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sigabrt

I am running Xcode 6.1. I started creating a Tic Tac Toe app, and when I try to run the unfinished (but no error) version of it, it automatically crashes and shows **appDelegate.swift** with a signal next to the code `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` that says `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. The 6.1.1 GSM seed is the same too.

I searched Google and Stackoverflow for the answer, but the only thing I found was I could create a exception breakpoint and also delete the DerivedData folder. When I try making a exception breakpoint, it does the same thing, except the signal is `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1`. And also nothing helps when I delete the DerivedData folder. Someone please help me!

Here is the code I currently have accomplished:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed0(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("It works!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is there any message besides this? Look in the console log window for additional info about the exception and post that here.

Comment: Have you deleted your this `button0` before from the `UIView` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with several projects, the way i have overcome this is to revert back to where the last successful build was or delete Xcode completely off your system and reinstall

both are a pain in the backside (this error must be a bug within Xcode) I hope apple resolves this soon

Answer (score 0):

Check if `@IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!` is connected with button on `main.storyboard`.